# Script Not Running Properly On Server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, permissions, scripts

I am having an issue with my webserver.  I am testing it out on a new kernel build and it seems as if I can't get one certain part running on it.  All of my scripts work except this one.  Every file for the time being has 777 permissions(I know it is wrong to do this).

The script that I am having issues is one that opens the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and saves it to a string for editing.  Once the edits are done it saves string to a `tempinterfaces` file which then that file gets `cp` over to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

I know this script works on my old server so it is not a script issue.  I had to manually install apache2.2.29 on my new Kernel.  This script does not even write to the `tempinterfaces` file as it is never updated.  The `cp` command is not executed either during this script execution.

Any suggestions on solving this problem?

Edit*  The script is being executed as in for the fact that there is no 500, 404, 200 error during attempted execution of the script.  I have a feeling it has something to do with permissions but I can't seem to focus in on the issue.  I am also new to working with permissions.

ipChange Script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8417964/

Comment: How did you execute your script? Could you post some parts of your script to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: @c0rp added my ipChange script, let me know if you need anything else.  This is triggered via submit button ran through javascripts and also some jquery to send some data to the file such as IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading apache2 from archives.  Did not know you could do that.  I felt like I was missing some file but could be wrong.  I also needed to change the permissions on `/etc/network/interfaces` to `666` and was able to get it working.